# String Reverse in Assembly language x86

Tags: string, assembly, x86, reverse, irvine32

I'm new to assembly language and I have this code that is suppose to reverse the string length, now I know I'm close but the program keeps crashing on me for whatever reason that is. The problem is in the STRREV PROC. What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    prompt BYTE "Enter String: ", 0
    response BYTE 50 DUP(0)
    message BYTE " Message entered. ",0
.code   

swap MACRO a,b 

    xor a,b
    xor b,a
    xor a,b

endM

STRQRY PROC
   push ebp
   mov  ebp, esp
   push edx
   push ecx

   mov edx, [ebp+8]
   call writestring

   mov ecx, SIZEOF response
   mov edx, OFFSET response
   call readstring


   pop ecx
   pop edx
   pop ebp  
   ret 4

STRQRY ENDP

STRLEN PROC 
           push ebp 
           mov  ebp, esp
           push ebx
           push ecx

           mov edx,[ebp+16]

           mov eax, 0


counter:
           mov cl,[edx+eax]

           cmp cl, 0       

           JE  done

           inc eax 

           jmp counter

done:
           pop ecx
           pop ebx
           pop ebp
           ret 4

STRLEN ENDP

STRREV proc
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp

    push OFFSET response   
    call STRLEN

    mov edx, [ebp+8]
    mov esi, 0
    dec eax

reverseloop:   

    mov ah, [edx+esi]
    mov al, [edx+eax]

    swap ah, al

    mov [edx+esi],ah
    mov [edx+eax],al

    inc esi
    dec eax

    cmp esi, eax
    jb reverseloop
    ja finish

finish:
    pop ebp
    ret 4

STRREV endp

main PROC

    push OFFSET prompt
    call STRQRY

    call writedec 

    mov edx,OFFSET message
    call WriteString

    push eax 
    call STRREV

    mov edx, OFFSET response
    call WriteString

     exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: why do you `mov edx, [ebp+16]` in STRLEN?

Comment: It's +8 to first argument, and he mistakenly adds another +8 for the 2x `push` after `mov ebp,esp`, not realizing the `push` affects only `esp`, not `ebp` (values of those two push instructions are at `[esp+0]` == `[ebp-8]` and `[esp+4]` == `[ebp-4]` ... so he's doing `[ebp+16]` instead of `[esp+16]` or `[ebp+8]`.  ... Anyway he didn't even bother to debug it, or he missed the fact that the `strlen` code loads wrong address of string at that point. Plus I have seen this source on SO already, I wonder how they manage to produce the same bug each time, funny.

Comment: But there are more bugs in that code. Keep debugging (you will probably note after some time, that registers `eax` and `al` share some bits, as well as `ah` does, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your function is changing AL and AH register and then using EAX as pointer.
 I decided to write a new function based  on your code, read it carefully and debug your code using the right emulator.

```
STRREV proc 

;opening the function 
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp

push OFFSET response  
call STRLEN

mov edx, [ebp+8]   ;edx = offset string to reverse 
mov esi, 0
dec eax    

mov ebx,edx       ;ebx stores the pointer to the first character  
add ebx,eax`       ;now ebx store the pointer to the last character before the '$'  

reverseloop:   


mov ah, [edx]    ;ah stores the value at string[loop count]
mov al, [ebx]    ;al stores the value at string[len-loop count-1]

;"swap ah,al"  is logiclly unnecessary
;better solution: 

mov [ebx],ah     ; string[loop count] = string[len-loop count-1]
mov [edx],al     ; string[len-loop count-1] = string[loop count]

inc edx          ;increment  of the right-most pointer
dec ebx          ;decrement of the right-most pointer 

cmp ebx, eax     ;compares the left-most pointer to the right-most 
jb reverseloop
jmp finish      ;"ja", there is no need to check a condition twice 

finish:
pop ebp
ret 4

STRREV endp
```

Comment: Better for performance not to use separate parts of the same register, that causes false dependencies on some CPUs.  e.g. use `movzx eax, byte [edx]` and `movzx ecx, byte [ebx]` to avoid writing partial registers at all.  (And still store as `mov [ebx], al` / `mov [edx], cl` with byte stores).